# 401.2 in Failed Request Log Files

Tags: authentication, iis-7.5

I have hosted a website with framwork 4.0 on IIS 7.5 and only window authentication is enabled.

I keep getting this log file with error 401.2 in failedreqlogfile folder.

[image: Log file]

Here it shows RequestAuthType 1 RequestAuthType Anonymous and HTTPStatus 401 and substatus 2. What I am confused about is I have enabled only window authentication and disabled anonymus authentication then why the requestauthtype is Anonymous?

Thanks,